# AWS Chime Meeting created with API - join with app

Tags: aws-chime-sdk, amazon-chime

Is it possible to create a meeting on AWS Chime using the API and then join that same meeting via the Chime app? Just using the meeting ID?

Answer (score 1):

The Amazon Chime client cannot be used to join a meeting created with the Amazon Chime SDK.
Refer here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/business-productivity/building-a-meeting-application-using-the-amazon-chime-sdk/